# Grunt Alter Template created from another task

Tags: gruntjs

I have a task in Grunt for `clean`, and I have another task for `copy`.  Basically, I clean out some stuff in one place, and then replace it with new stuff, going into the same places.  I can't figure out how to map my `copy.files.dest` such that it uses the values from `clean.env.files.src`, but switches the modifier.  So:

```
// Project settings
    yeoman: {
      // configurable paths
      app: 'app',
      dist: 'dist',
      prod:'L:/dist'
    }
// the prod sub-block of the clean task configuration
 prod:{
        files:[{
            dot:true,
            src:[
                '<%= yeoman.prod% >/scripts',
                 '<%= yeoman.prod% >/styles',
                 '<%= yeoman.prod% >/views',
                 '<%= yeoman.prod% >/*.html',
                 '<%= yeoman.prod% >/images'        

            ]
        }]
      }

//the prod sub-block of the copy task configuration
      prod:{
        files:[{
            expand:true,
            dot:true,
            cwd:'<%= yeoman.dist  %>',
            dest:'<%= yeoman.prod  %>',
            //can i use the result files from this path, but use yeoman.dist instead of yeoman.prod?
            src:['<%= clean:prod:files:src %>'] 
        }]
      }
```

I want to use the template from `<%= clean:prod:files:src %>` but use an alternate configuration (in other words, that task uses `yeoman.prod`, whereas I want all the same files listed, and to do some would need to src from `yeoman.dist` instead).

**Is there a way to do this via grunt syntax, or do I have to rely on my (not shown) custom function instead?**

**Edit**, removed references to parent task, since they do not reflect what my code actually looks like.

Answer (score 3):

Always remember, Gruntfiles are javascript. They must be written in valid javascript.

`clean.prod:{}` isn't valid javascript.

The dot notation used in Grunt templates, `<%= clean.prod %>` is merely a template format to translate through javascript objects but not part of the javascript language itself.

So instead change your config to:

```
clean: {
  prod: {
    src: [ /* file patterns here */ ]
  }
}
```

and then access the `src` property of the `clean:prod` task with: `<%= clean.prod.src %>`.

I've taken the config out of the `files` array, as if you only have a single `src/dest` block within your target, `prod`, it is not needed. But if you wanted to access values from that location in the config, you have to remember `files` is an array. So accessing the first item of the array with the template would be: `<%= clean.prod.files[0].src %>`. But it is much simpler to just not use the `files` array unless needed.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects for more info about javascript objects and http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#templates for more info about grunt templates.

Comment: removed the references. I wasn't actually using `clean.prod:{}`. My system works, just want to improve the configuration so it's easier to maintain, and right now I'm using a different approach to do so.

If you have any tips on *that*, please let me know.  One of the resources on objects I consider to be the best is John Resig's, [How to become a Javascript Ninja] (http://www.manning.com/resig/).  Great Book. Had probably read 4 other manuals on OO javascript before then, and this was by far the best. Shame it wasn't around when I was first picking the js up

Comment: Your edited config is still invalid. Good luck though!

Comment: For now, my custom does what this question tries to achieve through a more sophisticated external template solution.